# lua - table maintenance (particle system related)

Tags: lua, coronasdk, lua-table, particles

The `update()` function below gets called on every frame of a game. If the `Drop` particle has y value greater than 160 I want to remove it from the table. The problem is that I get "attempt to compare number with nil" errors, on the line notated below:

```
local particles = {};

function update()
    local num = math.random(1,10);
    if(num < 4) then
        local drop = Drop.new()
        table.insert ( particles, drop );
    end

    for i,val in ipairs(particles) do
        if(val.y > 160) then --ERROR attempt to compare number with nil
            val:removeSelf(); --removeSelf() is Corona function that removes the display object from the screen
            val = nil;
        end
    end
end
```

What am I doing wrong? Obviously `val` is nil, but I don't understand why the table iteration would find val in the first place since I set it to nil when it's y value gets larger than 160.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, they were all helpful. Here is what ended up working for me. The `table.remove` call is necessary to keep the loop running properly.

```
for i = #particles, 1, -1 do
    if particles[i].y > 160 then
        local child = table.remove(particles, i)
        if child ~= nil then
            display.remove(child)
            child = nil
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking in the wrong place, the problem isn't that `val` is `nil`, it's `val.y` that's `nil`.  See this example:

```
> x=nil
> if x.y > 10 then print("test") end
stdin:1: attempt to index global 'x' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
> x={y=nil}
> if x.y > 10 then print("test") end
stdin:1: attempt to compare number with nil
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

Also, when you set `val` to `nil`, that may not be doing anything (I believe `val` is a copy):

```
> t={"a", "b", "c", "d"}
> for i,val in ipairs(t) do print(i, val) end
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
> for i,val in ipairs(t) do if i==3 then print("delete", val); val=nil end end
delete  c
> for i,val in ipairs(t) do print(i, val) end
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
```

Edit: to delete an element from a table, you want `table.remove`:

```
> t[3]=nil
> for i,val in ipairs(t) do print(i, val) end
1   a
2   b
> t[3]="c"
> for i,val in ipairs(t) do print(i, val) end
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
> for i,val in ipairs(t) do if i==3 then print("delete", val); table.remove(t, i) end end
delete  c
> for i,val in ipairs(t) do print(i, val) end
1   a
2   b
3   d
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are allowed to modify the contents of a table while ***ipairs*** is iterating through it.  I vaguely remember reading that my hardcopy of the [Lua 5.1 Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-next), but I can't seem to locate it now.  When you set ***val*** to ***nil***, it removes an element from the ***particles*** table.

You might try processing the table in reverse, since your function is doing a full sweep of the ***particles*** table, conditionally removing some items:

```
for x = #particles, 1, -1 do
    if particles[x].y > 160 then
        particles[x]:removeSelf()
        particles[x] = nil
    end
end
```

Comment: According to the documentation that caveat only applies to next and pairs. Using ipairs to iterate over the table in numerical order should be okay. However, he is merely niling val, not the entry in the table http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-next

Comment: I tried this code (after adding -1 to the conditional and changing particles[x].val to particles[x].y), but I get this after it removes a particle: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)

Comment: Code updated per clua7's comments.  The nil reference error is puzzling.  The [`removeSelf()`](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/objectremoveself) call disassociates the object from Corona's display machinery, and setting it to `nil` removes it from the `particles` table, ready for garbage collection.  Then,  `x` should decrement, moving on to the next object in the table.  What line is reported when you get "attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)?"

Answer (score 0):

JeffK's solution should work, but I think the reason it will work is not because of the fact that he's traversing the list backwards, but because he is setting `particles[i] = nil` instead of `val = nil`. If you run `val = nil` you're only setting the local copy of val to nil, not the entry in the table.

Try this:

```
for i,val in ipairs(particles) do
    if(val.y > 160) then
        particles[i]:removeSelf()
        particles[i] = nil;
    end
end
```

Comment: I tried your code. I don't get the error now, but the strange thing is that it will only remove one object. After that it never enters the for loop again. It's like the particles table is getting set to nil somehow.

Comment: What is probably happening then the first element in the list gets nil'd, then since the first element is nil the loop never runs again (as the iteration stops when it reaches a nil index). You might be able to solve this by compacting the array at the end of the loop so that it does not have gaps, although that might be tricky.

Comment: Yes, when a `nil` value is reached, the for loop will stop.  I've updated my answer with `table.remove` that performs the delete correctly.